# OpenCV in Borland C++ 2009

Tags: c++, opencv

When I try to use OpenCv 2.3 in Borland, I add these folders to the project:

```
C:\Program Files\opencv2.3.1\build\include\opencv2
C:\Program Files\opencv2.3.1\include\opencv
```

and include

```
opencv_core231.lib
opencv_highgui231.lib
opencv_video231.lib
opencv_imgproc231.lib
```

Then become bunch of errors

```
[BCC32 Error] complex(194): E2316 '_fm_atan2l' is not a member of 'std'
[BCC32 Error] complex(199): E2316 '_fm_cosl' is not a member of 'std'
```

and etc. in file complex.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is that Borland cannot natively link to Visual C++ libraries, which if you downloaded the OpenCV 2.3 binary build, that is what you have. You could try to use Borland's `implib`. See this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599357/using-a-visual-c-dll-in-old-borland-c). However, I think this has the caveat that the code must only be C code due to the fact that Visual C++ mangles names when classes are used in DLLs. Since OpenCV does use classes, I have my doubts that `implib` will work.

So, I would recommend using [CMake](http://cmake.org/) to build [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/) with the Borland C++ target. Here is a GUI capture of what this should look like from CMake.

[image: CMake Borland target]

Take a look at [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) build guide.

Comment: When i'm trying to write in command line "make" (after CMAKE) it becomes the same errors in file complex..

Comment: previously i have tried to use OpenCv b5a and everything was compiled good.

Comment: What steps are you taking to build OpenCV 2.3.1?

Comment: i have download Cmake 2.8.6, installed and run, chose the main directory Opencv2.3.1 with make-files and chose another directory to build. then have open command line in Windows, chose that directory and typed make (cause mingw32-make didn't work) and it was the same errors in command line

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not own a copy of C++ Builder, so I cannot help you further figure out what the issue is. Have you tried to build OpenCV in MinGW or Visual Studio C++ Express with success?

Comment: With VS everything work great. But it's interesting whats wrong with Borland C++