# Compile dll in Qt with VS compiler to use it in Borland

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, dll, borland-c++

I have a package of C functions and I need to create DLL library from it, that can be used in C++ program. I haven't done any library before, so I am total beginner in that. I am working in Qt Creator.

My first try was to create it according to the manual [Creating shared libraries](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html), so I added these two lines to my project file:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += MYLIB_LIBRARY
```

Then I created mylib.h file

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#include "mylib_global.h"
#include "functions1.h"
#include "functions2.h"
#include "functions3.h"

class MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Mylib
{

public:
    Mylib(){};
};

#endif // MYLIB_H
```

Finally I added mylib_global.h:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_GLOBAL_H
#define MYLIB_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(MYLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // MYLIB_GLOBAL_H
```

To make functions usable in C++ I used these lines for each function in library

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

void foo();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

When compiling with MSVC2012 everything seems ok and I got some .dll file. But then I sent library to someone, who wanted **to use it in Borland C++**. He told me that I have to **compile it with some DEF file** to tell to VS compiler right names and **with `__stdcall` instead of `__cdecl`**. But I have no idea how to do it in Qt. Any explanation and help would be really appreciated. Thanks

P.S. I looked at posts [Using VS dll in old Borland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599357/using-a-visual-c-dll-in-old-borland-c) and [Import VS dll in C Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723301/import-vs-c-dll-in-c-builder), but they 
did not help me to understand the problem.

Comment: You probably will have a CRT conflict (multiple independent heaps and incompatible standard libraries) even if you get past the naming. I would tell the friend it is time to use a modern compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export the *foo* function, you need to tell the linker somehow.
What you were suggested is to use a .def file, which is quite easy.

Just create a file like    *exports.def*  in your project directory, and write in it something like:

`EXPORTS
        foo`

Then go to your library project settings -> Linker -> Input -> Module Definition File

and fill in your .def file name

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this, it seems easy. But I am still not sure how to do change __cdecl to __stdcall problem. Should I remove the mylib.h and mylib_global.h files and just write __stdcall to each function? Or is it so the DEF file is enough and I do not need to write anything specific to my function declarations?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Your safest bet is obviously to put __stdcall before each function.  Perhaps there's a global compiler setting for this.